# I am having a logical issue with evaluating Tic-Tac-Toe winning conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, conditional-statements, tic-tac-toe

I have been working on a Tic-Tac-Toe game and part of the winning logic is I decided to store conditional statements for winning (ie. three in a row, three in column, or three diagonal) in constant variables. The problem I am facing is that boolean `False` is the result of all the statements I did. I have proof with `print`s I inserted into my program.

Code:

```
# Create game cells
list = [' ' for n in range(10)]

# Coniditions for winning
O_ROW = (
    (list[1] == 'O' and list[2] == 'O' and list[3] == 'O') or
    (list[4] == 'O' and list[5] == 'O' and list[6] == 'O') or
    (list[7] == 'O' and list[8] == 'O' and list[9] == 'O')
)
O_COL = (
    (list[1] == 'O' and list[4] == 'O' and list[7] == 'O') or
    (list[2] == 'O' and list[5] == 'O' and list[8] == 'O') or
    (list[3] == 'O' and list[6] == 'O' and list[9] == 'O')
)
X_ROW = (
    (list[1] == 'X' and list[2] == 'X' and list[3] == 'X') or
    (list[4] == 'X' and list[5] == 'X' and list[6] == 'X') or
    (list[7] == 'X' and list[8] == 'X' and list[9] == 'X')
)
X_COL = (
    (list[1] == 'X' and list[4] == 'X' and list[7] == 'X') or
    (list[2] == 'X' and list[5] == 'X' and list[8] == 'X') or
    (list[3] == 'X' and list[6] == 'X' and list[9] == 'X')
)
O_DIAG = (
    (list[1] == 'O' and list[5] == 'O' and list[9] == 'O') or
    (list[3] == 'O' and list[5] == 'O' and list[7] == 'O')
)
X_DIAG = (
    (list[1] == 'X' and list[5] == 'X' and list[9] == 'X') or
    (list[3] == 'X' and list[5] == 'X' and list[7] == 'X')
)

def displayBoard():
    # Printing the game board
    print()
    print(f'\t {list[1]} | {list[2]} | {list[3]}')
    print('\t-----------')
    print(f'\t {list[4]} | {list[5]} | {list[6]}')
    print('\t-----------')
    print(f'\t {list[7]} | {list[8]} | {list[9]}')
    print()

def playBoard(pos, pl):
    # Position the play in the cell and check for already-placed cells
    if list[pos] != 'X' and list[pos] != 'O':
        list[pos] = pl.upper()
    else:
        print("Already played! Try again")

    # Determine winning condition or tie
    if O_ROW and O_COL and O_DIAG:
        print("O Wins!")
        sys.exit()
    elif X_ROW and X_COL and X_DIAG:
        print("X Wins!")
        sys.exit()


print('''Welcome to the game of Tic-Tac-Toe.
You will pick a play (X or O) and then pick from a place of 1 to 9 on
the board. Let's begin
''')

# Print for debugging
print(X_ROW)
print(X_COL)
print(X_DIAG)
print(O_ROW)
print(O_COL)
print(O_DIAG)
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the game of Tic-Tac-Toe.
You will pick a play (X or O) and then pick from a place of 1 to 9 on
the board. Let's begin

False
False
False
False
False
False
Play X or O?
```

What is the problem with the logic that they all evaluate to `False`?

If the reason for this logic error is encapsulating conditional statements into variables/constants, then pardon my ignorance. I tried to do this because the literal conditional statements all within the `if` statements later in the code looked too long and hard to read.

Comment: Of course it will be False before you start the game

Comment: `If the reason for this logic error is encapsulating conditional statements into variables/constants` - you are already aware of what the problem is :) They are all constant false's, because they only run once on startup when the board is empty

Comment: I do have a main game loop but I intentionally cut it out of the pasted code since I thought the code was already so many lines long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not upadting the values, so it's false everytime.
You can do someting like this.

```
import sys
# Create game cells
List = ['-' for n in range(10)]


# Coniditions for winning
def runGame():
    O_ROW = (
        not(List[1] == 'O' and List[2] == 'O' and List[3] == 'O') or
        not(List[4] == 'O' and List[5] == 'O' and List[6] == 'O') or
        not(List[7] == 'O' and List[8] == 'O' and List[9] == 'O')
    )
    O_COL = (
        not(List[1] == 'O' and List[4] == 'O' and List[7] == 'O') or
        not(List[2] == 'O' and List[5] == 'O' and List[8] == 'O') or
        not(List[3] == 'O' and List[6] == 'O' and List[9] == 'O')
    )
    O_DIAG = (
        not(List[1] == 'O' and List[5] == 'O' and List[9] == 'O') or
        not(List[3] == 'O' and List[5] == 'O' and List[7] == 'O')
    )
    X_ROW = (
        not(List[1] == 'X' and List[2] == 'X' and List[3] == 'X') or
        not(List[4] == 'X' and List[5] == 'X' and List[6] == 'X') or
        not(List[7] == 'X' and List[8] == 'X' and List[9] == 'X')
    )
    X_COL = (
        not(List[1] == 'X' and List[4] == 'X' and List[7] == 'X') or
        not(List[2] == 'X' and List[5] == 'X' and List[8] == 'X') or
        not(List[3] == 'X' and List[6] == 'X' and List[9] == 'X')
    )
    X_DIAG = (
        not(List[1] == 'X' and List[5] == 'X' and List[9] == 'X') or
        not(List[3] == 'X' and List[5] == 'X' and List[7] == 'X')
    )
    return(O_DIAG,O_ROW,O_COL,X_ROW,X_DIAG,X_COL)

def displayBoard():
    # Printing the game board
    print()
    print(f'\t {List[1]} | {List[2]} | {List[3]}')
    print('\t-----------')
    print(f'\t {List[4]} | {List[5]} | {List[6]}')
    print('\t-----------')
    print(f'\t {List[7]} | {List[8]} | {List[9]}')
    print()

def playBoard(pos, pl):
    # Position the play in the cell and check for already-placed cells
    if List[pos] != 'X' and List[pos] != 'O':
        List[pos] = pl.upper()
    else:
        print("Already played! Try again")

    # Determine winning condition or tie
    if not runGame()[0] or not runGame()[1] or not runGame()[2]  :
        displayBoard()
        print("O Wins!")
        sys.exit()
        
    elif not runGame()[3] or not runGame()[4] or not runGame()[5]:
        displayBoard()
        print("X Wins!")
        sys.exit()
    elif "-" not in List:
        print("It's a draw")
        sys.exit()


print('''Welcome to the game of Tic-Tac-Toe.
You will pick a play (X or O) and then pick from a place of 1 to 9 on
the board. Let's begin
''')

while (all(runGame())):
    displayBoard()
    pos=int(input("pos"))
    p1=input("X/O")
    playBoard(pos,p1)
    


playBoard(pos,p1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. I guess all along it was better to have put in it's own function.

Answer (score 0):

you evaluate all test after init list immediately,so no code modify the value of list,evey item in list is still empty string `' '`.
another problem is you did not call `displayBoard` or `playBoard`.

Answer (score 0):

First remark: a tic-tac-toe needs only 9 cells, but you create an array of 10 elements. You could replace 10 by 9 and shift all your indexing by 1 (indexing starts at 0):

```py
list = [' ' for n in range(10)]
```

And you could even rewrite it as `list = [' '] * 9` (which is equivalent but maybe easier to read)

So at this point, your game board is just 10 (or 9) cells, all containing `' '`

Then you evaluate whether a row/col/diag has been filled with

```
O_ROW = (
    (list[1] == 'O' and list[2] == 'O' and list[3] == 'O') or
    (list[4] == 'O' and list[5] == 'O' and list[6] == 'O') or
    (list[7] == 'O' and list[8] == 'O' and list[9] == 'O')
)
```

The conditional logic is correct (as far as tic-tac-toe rules are concerned), but obviously the result is `False` -> your game board is still empty (`' '` everywhere). So `O_ROW` (and others) will always be `False`! (changing the game board won't reevaluate magically your constants, you need to do it yourself)

Instead you could use a function to check whether a player has completed a row/col/diag. Something like:

```py
# board is your list
# player is 'O' or 'X'
def has_won(board, player):
    finished_row = (board[0] == player and board[1] == player and board[2] == player) or
    (board[3] == player and board[4] == player and board[5] == player) or
    (board[6] == player and board[7] == player and board[8] == player)
    # TODO!
    # finished_col =
    # finished_diag =
    return finished_row or finished_col or finished_diag
```

Then, whenever your board is updated, you check `has_won(board, 'O')` and `has_won(board, 'X')` to find if one player has won.